# Dev Express MVC Extensions with Razor - Controls Show as Lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, devexpress

Any DevExpress control I use, just renders a list. I’ve tried all 3 possible syntaxes (listed on the site below) and every time, the control I want to use (TreeView, NavBar, etc.) just renders as a bulleted list. Any ideas why? I’ve checked Google and the DevExpress support center, but I can’t find any issues like this.

DevExpress with razor guide: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9944

I just put this code on my index page to test that DevExpress is working:

```
@{Html.DevExpress().NavBar(settings =>  {
  settings.Name = "myNavBar";
  settings.Groups.Add("Group1").Items.Add("Item1-1");
  settings.Groups.Add("Group2").Items.Add("Item2-1");
  settings.Groups.FindByText("Group2").Expanded = false;

}).Render();}
```

When it reaches the page, it just shows a bulleted list:

- Group1

  - Item1-1
- Group2

Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project I was working on was being rendered inside another project. I just needed to get rid of my project's layout and add using statements to the cshtml pages:

```
@using DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI;
@using DevExpress.Web.Mvc;
```

The only problem I still have, is the scriptlet code gets highlighted red (but it builds/works fine and has intellisense).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that any required DevExpress' entry is not registered within the MasterPage (_Layout.cshtml) / Web.config http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8163. I suggest that you use specially designed Visual Studio Project Templates http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9145 to avoid missing any required DevExpress' entry.

Comment: I've been through those guides a dozen times. I have successfully created a starter project with a DevExpress template, but the problem is this project was already created for me (I'm building off an existing and much bigger project). I've compared my project's assemblies, web.configs, scripts, _Layout.cshtml, etc. to the starter project. As far as I can tell, they are identical

Comment: Ensure whether or not the ASPxHttpHandlerModule is registered properly http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8163